# Fluid full-width sub navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a fluid full-width navigation bar with a full-width sub navigation element below it.

The structure of my HTML is in this fiddle. Can someone help me with the CSS aspect to get the sub-nav to work properly? I can only get it to work if i explicitly set the width of the sub nav element

```
code is in the following fiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CG7Ff/

I'd prefer to do this without javascript if possible.

Comment: fix your markup, the subitems not showing

Comment: If you intend to use the button to trigger the sub-nav, you'll need to use JS.  Also, as I'm sure you're aware, a CSS-only sub-nav will only work with newer browsers.  That said, you can add: `.navbar:hover .nav-collapse{height:auto;}` to expand the sub-nav when hovering over the nav-bar.

Comment: @SamBattat, I'm using twitter bootstrap which hides the submenu when the viewport isnt a certain width. expand your screen.